# ldapsearch - Only return if value has both attributes

Tags: ldap, ldap-query

I am using ldapsearch like this:

`ldapsearch -Y GSSAPI ... '(&(objectClass=person)(employeeID=1*))' employeeID mail`

Essentially I want to return the employeeID and the mail address, but only if an employee has both. For example, if someone only has an employeeID but no mail, they shouldn't be included in the result set. In the above command, they still are returned. How can I limit it so that both requested attributes must be fulfilled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a wildcard in your filter -- mail=* means records where mail has any value. The specific filter in your example, modified to return records with the mail and employeeID attributes set would be:

```
(&(objectClass=person)(employeeID=1*)(mail=*)(employeeID=*))
```

Comment: Why the `(employeeID=*)` ?

Comment: Mostly for clarity -- to say I want to find accounts where attributes X and Y both have values, use the filter (&(X=*)(Y=*)). In this particular case, it's redundant to employeeID=1* ... I but I generally scope my query like that for testing (find a group of accounts that includes my own) and then drop the extra filter component for a "real" run. If the intent is to imitate a paged query by searching for employeeid=2*, employeeid=3*, etc ... then there's no need to add the employeeid=*.